# Why system freeze while install via apt?

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I have installed `sysstat` using `apt install sysstat` to check internal statistics. However, the system froze for approximately 10-15 minutes during the `Creating config file /etc/default/sysstat with new version` section. Is this normal behavior?

What is the purpose of `/etc/default/sysstat`?

My environment is `Linux cesar 5.10.0-23-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.179-1 (2023-05-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

```
root@cesar:~# apt install sysstat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  docker-scan-plugin linux-image-5.10.0-16-amd64
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libsensors-config libsensors5
Suggested packages:
  lm-sensors isag
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libsensors-config libsensors5 sysstat
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/688 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,129 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsensors-config.
(Reading database ... 42513 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libsensors-config_1%3a3.6.0-7_all.deb ...
Unpacking libsensors-config (1:3.6.0-7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsensors5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libsensors5_1%3a3.6.0-7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsensors5:amd64 (1:3.6.0-7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package sysstat.
Preparing to unpack .../sysstat_12.5.2-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking sysstat (12.5.2-2) ...
Setting up libsensors-config (1:3.6.0-7) ...
Setting up libsensors5:amd64 (1:3.6.0-7) ...
Setting up sysstat (12.5.2-2) ...

Creating config file /etc/default/sysstat with new version
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/sar.sysstat to provide /usr/bin/sar (sar) in auto mode
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sysstat.service.wants/sysstat-collect.timer → /lib/systemd/system/sysstat-collect.timer.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sysstat.service.wants/sysstat-summary.timer → /lib/systemd/system/sysstat-summary.timer.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/sysstat.service → /lib/systemd/system/sysstat.service.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u6) ...
```

Comment: Maybe your install drive is too slow. USB thumb drives for example are slow root drives. It might also be possible that your drive has a hardware malfunction. Please check `dmesg`.

Comment: Here is the post-install script which installs `/etc/default/sysstat`: https://salsa.debian.org/debian/sysstat/-/blob/master/debian/sysstat.postinst#L38 Something must have taken a lot of time in `ucf`, but I wouldn't know what. UCF has always been very fast for me.